# How do I get the DivX player browser plugin on my Mac to start working again?

Tags: mac, divx

The DivX player browser plugin has been working properly on my mac for a while, until it has recently stopped functioning.

The player loads properly, however, it appears to do nothing - the video fails to load, and the player fails to play.

This is consistent behavior across all web browsers.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest versions of Flash and DivX, this solved it for me.  Also upgrading to Snow Leopard has stopped Flash from being able to kill any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the divx components from /library/quicktime, /library/safari, ~/library/quicktime, and ~/library/safari.

Then re-install your divx software.

If you just re-install, without deleting, the installer package doesn't always overwrite every file in the codec bundle.